# How to redirect to login page from AuthorizationFilter in asp net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I return `ForbidResult()` it redirects to `AccessDenied` page as specified in startup. I want to do same with `UnauthorizedResult()` but redirect to `Login` page.

**P.S.**  I'm not using standard `Authorize` attribute in controller I have my own.

**Authorization Filter**:

```
public class MyFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    //

    public MyFilter()
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var hasPermission= ... ;
            if (!hasPermission)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

**startup**:

```
services.AddAuthentication.AddCookie(options =>
            {
               options.LoginPath = "/Accounts/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Accounts/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Accounts/AccessDenied";
            });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For redirecting to login page which is configured in `options.LoginPath = "/Accounts/Login";`, you could try code below:

```
public class MyFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    //

    public MyFilter()
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var hasPermission= ... ;
            if (!hasPermission)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new ChallengeResult(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can test with RedirectResult or context.Response.Redirect("/Accounts/Login");

```c#
public class MyFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    //

    public MyFilter()
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var hasPermission= ... ;
            if (!hasPermission)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Accounts/Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. RedirectResult works fine but i think it's better to use ChallengeResult in that case.

Comment: What would be the best way to transfer some sort of TempData from the filter to the action method on redirect? Like if I wanted to add a Model error? Thanks.