# C# .net core redirect via Attribute, without computing and running code inside controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, attributes

To simplify problem, let's say I have controller with custom attribute, like this:

```
[Route("Authenticated")]
[AccessTokenAuthentication]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticated()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I dont want to see this if user is not authenticated.");
    return View("AuthenticatedUserView");
}
```

Based on logic inside `AccessTokenAuthentication`Attribute which looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AccessTokenAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
       string Token;
       filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("TokenCookie", out Token);
       if (Token != null)
       {
           //from DI Container
           Tokenhelper helper= (Tokenhelper)filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(Tokenhelper));
           if (helper.IsTokenValid(Token))
           {
               return;
           }
       }
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("Login"); //redirect to login.   
       return;
    }
}
```

It either verifies user and opens `AuthenticatedUserView` page or redirects to `Login` page,
This all works as expected, except when user is redirected program still executes `Console.WriteLine("I dont want to see this if user is not authenticated.")` Line.

**Is there a way to redirect from attribute without executing logic inside controller action ?**
*(maybe respond with 402 or 401, and then somehow redirect ??) I don't know.*

**Thanks for Help !**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to redirect from attribute without executing logic
> inside controller action ?

Don't call `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("Login");`.
Set **`filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult (or RedirectToRouteResult)`** instead.

In `IAuthorizationFilter`, to prevent the execution of the action code and redirect to the login page, you should prevent the program from entering the original action by **changing the Result of AuthorizationFilterContext**, as shown below:

```
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Login/Index");
```

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853415/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-from-authorizationfilter-in-asp-net-core).